# How to find a gene of interest in a dataset and print all the values

Tags: python, r, excel, pandas, bioinformatics

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Gene       baseMean  log2FoldChange  lfcSE        stat           pvalue       padj

7SK         30.492  -0.892099279    0.4798019   -0.917210735    0.813808009  0.62064135

A1BG        2.8389  -0.916542309    0.5080946   -0.032557531    0.854027437  NA

A1BG-AS1    19.2657 -0.734784397    0.6184409   -0.056245298    0.355146396  0.976130671
```

then I have another list where I have all the name of my genes of interest that are written in just one column:

```
Gene (e.g)
7Sk
ABL2
BMP
```

So now my question is how can I extract all the columns with all the values present in the dataset if I have an exact match between the gene of interest and the genes in the dataset?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you mean either `dat1[dat1$Gene %in% dat2$Gene,]` or `merge(dat1, dat2, by="Gene")`?

Comment: I used merge by gene and it worked perfectly! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I don't know why it was closed (it is not without focus IMO) nor why I cannot reopen it. oldboy12, if it is ever reopened, ping me and I'll add this as an answer.

Comment: @r2evans - at least as far as the Excel tag goes, questions normally get closed as "needs more focus" if they don't have any code already and are asking for a code solution. Not knowing R well, I voted to close based on a read of the question. Voted to reopen, though the fact that this also seems like tag spam (python, pandas, excel, and R) makes me a bit hesitant to.

Comment: I find it interesting how different tag-communities within SO interpret the close-reasons differently at times. Within [tag:r], I would suggest to oldboy12 that code be added, and might (eventually) VTC based on *"seeking debugging help but needs information"*, but "focus" would not be my first thought. Similarly within [tag:r], it's not uncommon to see "what have you tried" and VTC out of "spite" (in a sense). Thanks @BigBen!

Comment: @NelsonGon, will you consider voting to reopen?

Comment: @BigBen I added those tags because reading around I noticed that the same command could have been performed through Panda or Python or Excel.. I do not think that is out of focus and actually I think it could be very helpful for people that like me have not so much experience.

Comment: @oldboy12 - Stack Overflow doesn't work that way... It's confusing, because your question doesn't stipulate *which* of those you want a solution in. That's why it seems like "tag spamming." Part of how the site works is that you're supposed to *try it first* and show where you're having problems.

Comment: @bigben thanks a lot then now I see your point.. I will keep it in mind for the next question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An R implementation:

```r
dat1[dat1$Gene %in% dat2$Gene,]
#   Gene baseMean log2FoldChange     lfcSE       stat   pvalue      padj
# 1  7SK   30.492     -0.8920993 0.4798019 -0.9172107 0.813808 0.6206413

merge(dat1, dat2, by = "Gene", all = FALSE)
#   Gene baseMean log2FoldChange     lfcSE       stat   pvalue      padj
# 1  7SK   30.492     -0.8920993 0.4798019 -0.9172107 0.813808 0.6206413
```

Data:

```r
dat1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
Gene       baseMean  log2FoldChange  lfcSE        stat           pvalue       padj
7SK         30.492  -0.892099279    0.4798019   -0.917210735    0.813808009  0.62064135
A1BG        2.8389  -0.916542309    0.5080946   -0.032557531    0.854027437  NA
A1BG-AS1    19.2657 -0.734784397    0.6184409   -0.056245298    0.355146396  0.976130671")

dat2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
Gene
7SK
ABL2
BMP")
# changed "7Sk" to "7SK" to create a match
```